# Trouble with static properties being undefined in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So I'm writing some coffeescript for a project and I'm trying to create some static properties in a class. I've been following another file in the codebase that does the same thing successfully, but mine isn't working.

My Code

```
class Messages
    @toggleUnreadConversations:()->
        # This is the line in question, Messages is defined with all the 
        # functions but the property ViewOnlyUnread is undefined

        Messages.ViewOnlyUnread = !Messages.ViewOnlyUnread

    @init:->
        @ViewOnlyUnread = false
```

Other code in the code base that successfully uses static properties

```
class Map
   @CacheRealtor: (realtor) ->
        realtor.realtor_id = parseInt(realtor.realtor_id)

        # Here the static property IdToRealtorMap is defined 
        Map.IdToRealtorMap[parseInt(realtor.realtor_id)] = new Realtor()
   @Init: ->
       @IdToListingMap = []
       @IdToRealtorMap  = []
```

From what I can tell these init functions are being called the same way, when the page loads init is called. Both classes are static classes, there is never an instance of either of them being created. Does anyone have any idea to what could be the issue?

Comment: Messages.ViewOnlyUnread evaluates to undefined when that line of code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` function is setting an **instance variable**, but your `toggleUnreadConversations` function is trying to reference it as though it a property of your class.

You should use `@` to refer to the instance variable that `init` sets:

```
class Messages
  @toggleUnreadConversations: ->

    # reference the instance variable
    @ViewOnlyUnread = !@ViewOnlyUnread

  @init: ->
    @ViewOnlyUnread = false
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I never actually initialize an instance of the class. When my page loads I simply call Messages.init(). My goal is to make it a class property, the Message class is simply a way of putting all this functionality inside of a namespace.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. In that case I would recommend making `Messages` just an object: `Messages = {}`, and then setting properties of that object. The `class` in CoffeeScript is really intended for objects w/ a constructor that are going to be instantiated.